# PYTHON How to count letters in words without special characters

Tags: python, file-io

I have a code that counts letters in words excluding special characters at the end. I just can't figure out a way to get it to exclude special character at the beginning also.

My code so far:

```
inFile = open( 'p.txt', "r" ).readlines()

myResults = []
for i in range( 20 ):
   myResults.append( 0 )

mySpecialList = [ '-', '+', '#', '@', '!', '(', ')', '?', '.', ',', ':', ';', '"', "'", '`' ]

for line in inFile:
   words = str.split( line )
   for word in words:
      if word not in mySpecialList:
         if word[ -1 ] not in mySpecialList :
            myResults[ len( word ) ] += 1
         else :
            myResults[ len( word ) - 1 ] += 1


print( myResults )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some simple code to count all the alpha numeric letters of a single word.

```
word = "Hello World!"
count = 0
for c in word:
   if c.isalnum():
      count +1 
print( count )
```

If you wanted to use your special characters you could adapt the code to look like

```
    mySpecialList = ['*', '!']
    word = "Hello World!"
    count = 0
    for c in word:
       if c not in mySpecialList:
          count +1 
    print( count )
```

Comment: Brian Cain could you please help as how to adapt the code to this? To still be able to count all words in the file and then make a list of how many x-long character words are there

Comment: You have most of the code in place already.  Most of your remaining tasks to accomplish your goal are to incorporate my answer into your code.  You should be able to replace your "for word in words:" loop content with my answer to produce your end result.

Comment: It doesnt really help me since I'm trying to get a count of all x-number letters. If you can just execute the code you'll see what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, try it!
For example you can split string and after findall you have a list with all words.

```
import re

string = "Hello World, Hi + Say"
print(re.findall(r"[\w']+", string))
```

Comment: aarexer I don't really follow your solution. I want to get something like this
[0, 73, 63, 750, 592, 859, 884, 790, 592, 418, 279, 181, 83, 34, 12, 6, 2, 0, 1, 0]

Where 0 is count of 0-letter words Where 73 is count of 1-letter words Where 630 is count of 2-letter words

Comment: It's something like that?
"Hello World" 
>> [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverseword(user_input):
    words=str(user_input).split(" ")
    newWords = [word[::-1] for word in words] 
    newSentence = " ".join(newWords) 
    return newSentence
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        ispresent=0
        splcharlist=['-', '+', '#', '@', '!', '(', ')', '?', '.', ',', ':', ';', '"', "'", '`'," "]
        user_input=input("Enter the input:")
        print(len(user_input))
        ccount=0
        new_input=""
        ch_count=0
        if len(user_input)>100:
            for eletter in user_input:
                if eletter not in splcharlist:
                    ccount=ccount+1
                ch_count=ch_count+1 
                if ccount>100:
                    break

            new_input=user_input[:100]  
        else:
            new_input=user_input


        print("This is for your input:",user_input)
        print("input with limit :"+str(new_input))
        print(len(new_input))

        print("The Reverse lists is: ",reverseword(new_input))

        if "stop" in user_input:
            break
```